# PhoneGap/Cordova App based on Swift Project

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova, swift

PhoneGap/Cordova for iOS is currently based on an ObjectiveC project.

**How can I run a PhoneGap/Cordova app based on a Swift project?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordova-ios is built with Objective-C, and I don't believe that's going to change any time soon. You can use Swift and Objective-C in the same project though, so nothing is stopping you from writing iOS plugins in Swift. You will have to add a bridging header though. You can see an example of a Swift cordova plugin [here](https://github.com/edewit/cordova-plugin-hello/tree/swift).

Comment: If you are working with Swift 3 I recently published a blog post on how to develop a Cordova plugin in Swift with example code repo.  Find it here https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-3-for-ios-e314acf68a47#.1xxihldrj

Answer (score 1):

The other answer works but it is manual.

You can automate how you convert a project to swift from Cordova's output. Take a look at this project:

https://github.com/akofman/cordova-plugin-add-swift-support

That project has a hook that runs after platform add and it will add a bridging header as well as the proper settings to make the project work with Swift code. You can use it as a plugin.

Comment: I provide a tutorial on how to do this here https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-3-for-ios-e314acf68a47#.1xxihldrj